# "X provides the strongest support" vs. "most strongly supported by X"

Tags: meaning

Thanks for your attention.

I have trouble telling a difference, if any, between:

(1) The article provides the strongest support for which one of the following inferences?

and

(2) Which one of the following inferences is most strongly supported by the article?

To some extent, if I were to argue a difference, I would say that (1) is to demand an answer about what the article truly provides or states.

Comparatively, an answer for (2) would not necessarily stated/ mentioned by the article but nevertheless can still be deduced or inferred from the author's main idea.

I would be very graftul if you are willing to share your view.
Thanks a lot.

Leon

Comment: I guess it is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you cannot say ‘mostly strongly’

The motion is strongly supported by x (passive sentence)

X strongly supports the motion (active sentence)  have the same meaning.

Hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to ELL. If you look closely, you will see that the text of the question does not use the word "mostly." It uses the word "most." Please respond to the text, not the title.